# How to run School Days HQ in Ubuntu?

Tags: games, compatibility

I have tried several times to run School Days HQ through Wine and VirtualBox without much success.Usually text appears but images and animation fails to appear on screen.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Thank god it does not work. That game will scar you for life.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a good answer to my OWN question. Install the linux version of parallels (Workstation) in your machine and run a copy of windows 7 in it. Then install the CD of schooldays HQ in it.

Cheers.

Note: Bear in mind that parallels, in the first place use YOUR system resources, you must have enough resources to run this game, secondly the cost of parallels is high and unless linux is your main OS I would think investing in a paid virtualization software  would not be profitable but that's up to you¡